# Dynamic SQL in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE B.COL1 = A.COL1
AND B.COL2 = A.COL2
AND B.COL3 - A.COL3
AND B.COL4 = A.COL4
```

Now I want to tune the SQL query, that whenever any of the Columns in Table B has field value 'ALL' the where clause will not come into picture.

i.e. When it has a distinct value it will match with both the tables, when the field value is 'ALL' then to exclude from the where clause.

Alternatively,

```
I Need B.COL1= A.COL1 (When B.COL1 <> 'ALL')
Else NO WHERE clause with B.Col1 = A.Col1 (When B.COL1 = 'ALL')
```

Comment: Can you try rewriting your query with an explicit join?  As written, the query makes it hard to understand what the join condition is.

Comment: I would suggest you use a JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR wisely:

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE (B.COL1 = A.COL1 OR B.COL1='ALL')
AND (B.COL2 = A.COL2 OR B.COL2='ALL')
...
```

I would also suggest learning JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can use case statement to have a condition in where clause,

```
    SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE B.COL1 = 
              CASE 
              WHEN B.COL1 <> 'ALL' THEN A.COL1
              ELSE NULL
              END
      AND B.COL2 = A.COL2
      AND B.COL3 - A.COL3
      AND B.COL4 = A.COL4
```

Comment: This is what you need it right? You need for only B.COL1 or for all?

Comment: Case expression, not case statement. (It returns a value.)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with just IN:

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE B.COL1 IN (A.COL1, 'ALL')
AND B.COL2 IN (A.COL2, 'ALL')
AND B.COL3 IN (A.COL3, 'ALL')
AND B.COL4 IN (A.COL4, 'ALL')
```

What is actually going on may be more clear with a more verbose version using `AND/OR`, but the logic is exactly the same

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
FROM TABLE A, TABLE B
WHERE (B.COL1 = A.COL1 OR B.COL1 = 'ALL')
AND (B.COL2 = A.COL2 OR B.COL2 = 'ALL')
AND (B.COL3 = A.COL3 OR B.COL3 = 'ALL')
AND (B.COL4 = A.COL4 OR B.COL4 = 'ALL')
```

Comment: Hi Gareth, Seems the sql works fine. Let me further test with various scenario too.

Comment: Also, how can i exclude the blank values from any of the columns of Table B, if i prefer using the IN clause instead of AND/OR?? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend it, but I don't think there is much chance of your query using indexes anyway, so you could add a further predicate `AND '' NOT IN (B.COL1, B.COL2, B.COL3, B.COL4)` which will exclude rows where **any** of these columns in table B is blank.

Comment: I tried, with the option it does not work for me, also how do we do it with AND/OR?

Comment: Extend each column check from `(B.COL1 = A.COL1 OR B.COL1 = 'ALL')` to `(B.COL1 = A.COL1 OR B.COL1 = 'ALL' AND B.COL1 <> '')`

Comment: That did't worked either, I tried AND '' NOT IN (A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4). Seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN TABLE B ON 
(B.COL1 = A.COL1 AND B.COL2 = A.COL2 AND B.COL3 = A.COL3 AND B.COL4 = A.COL4)
OR
('ALL' IN (B.COL1, B.COL2, B.COL3, B.COL4))
```

but, if you work with large tables that complex filtering could slow down very much the execution, so I suggest to use a different syntax for complex JOINs

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM (
    SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
    FROM A 
    INNER JOIN B 
    ON (B.COL1 = A.COL1 AND B.COL2 = A.COL2 AND B.COL3 = A.COL3 AND B.COL4 = A.COL4)
) J1

UNION -- ALL ?

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM (
    SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4
    FROM A 
    INNER JOIN B ON ('ALL' IN (B.COL1, B.COL2, B.COL3, B.COL4))
) J2
```

This one should be much faster than previous one.

Also, I wonder about row duplicates.. with that syntax each row of table A will be added to result as many times as many rows in table B contains 'ALL'

I have added the `DISTINCT` clause to the `SELECT` to avoid duplicates (same problem affects `UNION` operator), so if you need duplicates, remove `DISTINCT` and use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Comment: Thanks for your response!
However, the sql for J1 block works absolutely fine when there are distinct values between table A & B. 
For the J2 block, the requirement is like when the value in table B for any of the field is 'ALL' it should fetch the results irrespective of any value.
e.g.

Comment: Thanks!

However, the sql for J1 block works absolutely fine when there are distinct values between table A & B. 

For the J2 block, the requirement is like when the value in table B for any of the field is 'ALL' it should fetch the results irrespective of any value.

e.g.

Table A has
SEQ     PRODUCT_ID    DEPTID
1          11204                  2020
2          11312                  4005
3          31314                 2005


Table B has
PRODUCT_ID    DEPTID
11204                  2020
ALL                     4005
31314                 ALL

Result A.SEQ
1, 2, 3 record

Comment: the really question is: if you have a record in Table B with: `PRODUCT_ID = 'ALL'` and  `DEPTID = '4005'`, you want to get the records of Table A with `DEPTID = '4005'` or all records of Table A without other conditions?